# Python how to subset a data frame with just the column indices?

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a huge dataframe with 282 columns and 500K rows. I wish to remove a list of columns from the dataframe using the column indices. The below code works for sequential columns.

```
df1 = df.ix[:,[0:2]]
```

The problem is that my column indices are not sequential.

For example, I want to remove columns 0,1,2 and 5 from df. I tried the following code:

```
df1 = df.ix[:,[0:2,5]]
```

I am getting the following error:

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Select columns other than *0,1,2,5* with:

```
df.ix[:, [3,4]+list(range(6,282))]
```

Or a little more dynamic:

```
df.ix[:, [3,4]+list(range(6,df.shape[1]))]
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thank you!

Comment: Cool. glad it helped!

Comment: Just to add an update: ```.ix``` has been deprecated. ```.iloc``` can be used in place of it. Rest everything remains the same.

Answer (score 0):

Is it a numpy array you've got? Try

```
df1 = df.ix[:, (0,1,2,5)]
```

or

```
df1 = df.ix[:, [0,1,2,5]]
```

or

```
data[:, [i for i in range(3)]+[5]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [np.r_[...]](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.r_.html) for concatenating slices along the first axis

DF:

```
In [98]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10, size=(5, 12)))

In [99]: df
Out[99]:
   0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11
0   0   7   2   9   9   0   7   3   5   8   8   1
1   4   9   0   4   0   2   4   8   8   7   1   9
2   2   1   1   2   7   4   4   6   1   2   9   8
3   1   5   0   8   2   2   4   1   1   4   8   4
4   4   6   3   2   2   4   1   6   2   6   9   0
```

Solution:

```
In [107]: df.iloc[:, np.r_[3:5, 6:df.shape[1]]]
Out[107]:
   3   4   6   7   8   9   10  11
0   9   9   7   3   5   8   8   1
1   4   0   4   8   8   7   1   9
2   2   7   4   6   1   2   9   8
3   8   2   4   1   1   4   8   4
4   2   2   1   6   2   6   9   0

In [108]: np.r_[3:5, 6:df.shape[1]]
Out[108]: array([ 3,  4,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11])
```

or

```
In [110]: df.columns.difference([0,1,2,5])
Out[110]: Int64Index([3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11], dtype='int64')

In [111]: df[df.columns.difference([0,1,2,5])]
Out[111]:
   3   4   6   7   8   9   10  11
0   9   9   7   3   5   8   8   1
1   4   0   4   8   8   7   1   9
2   2   7   4   6   1   2   9   8
3   8   2   4   1   1   4   8   4
4   2   2   1   6   2   6   9   0
```